# LTI systems in convolution representation

Tags: dynamical-systems, convolution

LTI systems in state space representation are systems of the form:

\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)=\mathbf{Ax}(t)+\mathbf{Bu}(t)
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbf{y}(t)&=&\mathbf{Cx}(t)+\mathbf{Du}(t)
\end{eqnarray}

where $\mathbf{x}$ is the state vector, $\mathbf{u}$ is the input and $\mathbf{y}$ is the output. These systems satisfy the superposition principle only if the initial condition $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ holds. Let us refer to the class of these systems with the aforementioned initial condition as $\Sigma_{LTI}^0$.

Now a different class of systems, namely $\Sigma_{conv}$ are the ones that are represented by a convolution integral, i.e. the input-output behaviour of the system is described by:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau) \mathbf{u}(t-\tau)d\tau
\end{equation}

My question is whether it is true that every system in $\Sigma_{LTI}^0$ admits a representation in $\Sigma_{conv}$? If yes, how?

**Note:** I understand that my question boils down to  finding a function $h$ such that (assume for simplicity that $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{I}$ and $\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{0}$):

\begin{equation}
\int_0^t e^{\mathbf{A}(t-\tau)}\mathbf{Bu}(\tau)d\tau= \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau) \mathbf{u}(t-\tau)d\tau
\end{equation}

**Update:** Let us assume that there exists a $h\in\mathcal{L}^2(\Re;\Re^n)$ such that an LTI system is equivalent to a convolution system and assume for simplicity that the input is one-dimensional. Then, these have identical impulse responses, hence for $u(t)=\delta(t)$ we have:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^t e^{\mathbf{A}(t-\tau)}\mathbf{B}\delta(\tau)d\tau= \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(\tau) \delta(t-\tau)d\tau
\end{equation}

Therefore:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^t e^{\mathbf{A}(t-\tau)}\mathbf{B}\delta(\tau)d\tau= h(t) \implies
h(t)=e^{\mathbf{A}t}\mathbf{B}
\end{equation}

But then:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^t e^{\mathbf{A}(t-\tau)}\mathbf{Bu}(\tau)d\tau= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\mathbf{A}(t-\tau)}\mathbf{Bu}(\tau)d\tau
\end{equation}

Doesn't look good! So, if there is no mistake in the above procedure, there is no $h$ that fulfills my requirements. Then, what is the connection between the aforementioned classes of systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transfer function of the given system is
$$
\mathbf{Y}(s)=[\mathbf{D}+\mathbf{C}(s\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})^{-1}\mathbf{B}]\mathbf{U}(s)
$$
and it establishes an input-output relationship written compactly as
$$
\mathbf{Y}(s)=\mathbf{G}(s)\mathbf{U}(s)
$$
Using the convolution property of the Laplace transform, we have:
$$
\mathbf{y}(t)=\mathbf{g}(t)*\mathbf{u}(t)
$$
where $g(t)=(\mathscr{L}^{-1}\mathbf{G})(t)$. Therefore, every system in state-space form can be written in an equivalent input-output representation using the convolution operation.

Answer (score 2):

Initial conditions can be represented as impulse responses applied to the system at time $t=0$. In other words, you can add a new column $x(0)$ to the $B$ matrix and extend your input function to $\pmatrix{u(t) \\ \delta(t)}$. In a way, you treat the initial condition as a perturbation to the zero initial condition system since

$$
x(t) = Ce^{At}x_0 + \int_0^t Ce^{\mathbf{A}(t-\tau)}\mathbf{Bu}(\tau)d\tau
$$

Note that, $\delta(t)$ function only makes sense under the integral sign.

Therefore, every LTI system in $\Sigma^0_{LTI}$ is a member of $\Sigma^{x_0}_{LTI}$ with the special case $x_0=0$.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Where does $\Sigma_\text{conv}$ appear?

Comment: Causality makes it possible to extend the lower limit of the integral to $-\infty$ and you can add an indicator function to cut off the response and extend the integral limit to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that your forgot to add that your solution for $h(t)=e^{\mathbf{A}t}\mathbf{B}$ is valid for $t>0$

And that makes sense: assuming for one moment ${\bf D}=0$, we have a system in which the output is given by a first-order linear differential equation, which indeed corresponds to an exponential $h(t)$ (causal, i.e., $h(t) =0$ for $t<0$). Adding ${\bf D}\ne0$ you're just adding a ${\bf D} \; \delta(t)$ term, so the conclusion would be that $\Sigma_{LTI}^0$ is a (small) subset of $\Sigma_{conv}$, namely, that of the LTI which $h(t)$ is given by the sum of an (casual) exponential and a Dirac delta.

This reasoning should be extended to multidimensional systems, though. Now, assume ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf x}$ are one-dimension, but we are allowed to increase the dimension of ${\bf x}$ arbritrarily (which is equivalent to extend arbitrarily the order of the ODE). Then, it's another story.

BTW, if you are familiar with discrete LTI systems, the analogy would be $\Sigma_{LTI}^0 \leftrightarrow AR(1)$ (autoregresive processes of order 1, i.e., one pole), which indeed corresponds to a subset of all LTI casual systems.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more one that and actually show how you justify this equivalence. Start assuming that $\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{0}$ and then generalize if possible.

Answer (score -2):

Another aspect to consider is that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}_1(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t-\tau) \mathbf{x}(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau,
\end{equation}
is comparable with
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{y}_2(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}h(t-\tau) \mathbf{x}(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau.
\end{equation}
Only if the system under study is causal, since the integrand in the first equation would be zero for $t>\tau$ if $h(t)$ was the impulse response of a causal system. Note that in the first integral, $\mathbf{y}_1(t)$ is the integral under the area for different values of $t$. On the other hand, in the latter equation, as $t\rightarrow \infty$, $\mathbf{y}_2(t)$ ponders the contribution of the continuous time delay $t$. Thus, although both $\mathbf{y}_1$ and $\mathbf{y}_2$ are outputs of linear systems, the upper bound in the integral is a major difference to consider.

Complementary, it can be found that, as mentioned in a previous answer, for a time-invariant linear and causal system like the one presented:
\begin{equation}
y(t)= Ce^{A(t-t_0)}x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t}Ce^{A(t-\tau)}Bu(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau + Du(t),
\end{equation}
where the convolution integral upper bound, is $t$, holds (the complete proof to obtain the convolution response, without using Laplace or Fourier transforms can be found in Lecture 6 of "Linear Systems Theory" by J.P. Hespanha). Therefore, the linear systems response is a convolution, but not only the initial conditions, but also the causality of the system plays a crucial role in the problem.

Hope this contributes to getting an appropriate answer to your problem. Cheers!

Comment: The $\tau$ is what is integrated away, not $t.$

Comment: Correct, thank you for pointing that out (I will edit my comment to clearly state the problem I see). In that regard, I can see that there is a noticeable difference between $\mathbf{y}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(\tau) \mathbf{x}(t-\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau,$ and $\mathbf{y}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t}h(\tau) \mathbf{x}(t-\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$. Although the operator is still linear, I do not clearly see its connection with the solution of the differential equation.